# 遠隔指示で充電ステーションに戻り充電に入る方法を知りたい

Tags: aibo-developer

広いフロアでの飼育を検討しております。

一定時間のみ散歩して決まった時刻になったら、充電ステーションに戻るように遠隔で指示を出したいです。
APIを確認したところ、MoveToPositionを使えば充電ステーションを目的地に設定できるように見えますが、これだけで充電ステーションで充電を開始するのか分かりません。
このコマンドだけでOKか？もしくは、何か工夫が必要かご教授いただきたくよろしくお願いいたします。
お散歩時間を制限することで、広いフロアでも電池切れを防止できるのではないかと考えてます。

Answer (score 1):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。
回答が遅くなってしまい、失礼いたしました。

> MoveToPositionを使えば充電ステーションを目的地に設定できるように見えますが、これだけで充電ステーションで充電を開始するのか分かりません。
> このコマンドだけでOKか？もしくは、何か工夫が必要かご教授いただきたくよろしくお願いいたします。

現在公開している API では、MoveToPosition で充電ステーションのそばへ近づかせることはできますが、
充電ステーションに乗って充電を開始させることはできません。

確実に充電を行うことはできませんが、
以下のようにすることで充電ステーションで充電を開始することが期待できます。
 
aibo はバッテリー残量が少なくなると自動で充電ステーションに戻り、充電を開始します。
したがいまして、Cognition API のHungryStatus でバッテリー残量を確認し、
HungryStatus が hungry のときは MoveToPosition で充電ステーションのそばへ移動させ、
移動が終わったら SetMode で指示待ち中から状態を戻すと、自動で充電ステーションに戻ることが期待できます。
 
 
今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム